# Sequence $\{ e^{2 \pi i n x}\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and Paley-Wiener space $PW(0,1)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let us consider the Paley-Wiener space:
$$PW(0,1):=\{f\in L^2(\mathbb R)\cap C(\mathbb R),\ \operatorname{supp}\hat f\subset (0,1) \}.$$
Let us consider $\{ e^{2 \pi i n x}\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$, for $x\in (0,1)$. Let $\{\operatorname{sinc}(t-\lambda_n)\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be the sequence of its Fourier transforms.

Is it a Riesz basis in the whole space $PW(0,1)$? How can prove (or disprove) it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer to your other question: [Riesz basis of Paley-Wiener space.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1746062/riesz-basis-of-paley-wiener-space/1836743#1836743).

> Consider the Paley-Wiener space
>
> $$ PW_{\frac{1}{2}} := \{ f \in L^2 (\mathbb{R}) \; | \; \text{supp} \;\hat{f} \subseteq [-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}] \} $$
>
> Then the collection $\{\text{sinc} (x - n) \}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is an orthonormal basis for $PW_{\frac{1}{2}}$. Recall now that a Riesz basis for a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ is a collection $\{U e_k \}_{k \in I}$, where $U : \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ is a topological isomorphism and $\{e_k\}_{k \in I}$ is an orthonormal basis for $\mathcal{H}$.
>
> Clearly, the collection $\{\text{sinc} (x - n) \}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ forms a Riesz basis for $PW_{\frac{1}{2}}$, but the collection $\{\text{sinc} (x - n) \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with the index set $\mathbb{N}$ is not.